# How to verify binary SHA checksum

Tags: hashsum

I have a `file.bin` and `file.bin.sha`. The `file.bin.sha` has 32 bytes and contains binary data. How can I verify the checksum? `sha256sum` complains about `no properly formatted SHA256 checksum lines found`.

Comment: could you check with `sha1sum`?

Comment: Same `no properly formatted SHA1 checksum lines found` error.

Comment: If you want to compare the two files in order to check if they are identical, you can use "cmp" too. You can also check https://www.lifewire.com/cmp-linux-command-4095389

Comment: The manpage seems to mention `-b --binary` option to read in binary mode. Have you tried with that option?

Comment: `the --binary and --text options are meaningless when verifying checksums`

Comment: The "get a bigger hammer" approach: generate the checksum of `file.bin` with `openssl sha256 -binary -out file.bin.sha2 file.bin`, then `cmp file.bin.sha file.bin.sha2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the 256-bit binary value to its hex ascii representation, and append the filename to create a check file that sha256sum will like:

```
echo $(od -An -tx1 file.bin.sha | tr -d '\n ') file.bin > my256
sha256sum -c my256
```

---

- `od` - octal (binary, hex) dump of file
- `-An` - suppress addresses
- `-tx1` - print as one byte values, hex
- `tr -d '\n '` - suppress blanks and newlines in the output